# What is the difference between [myString length] and myString.length in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, square-bracket, braces

I'm currently learning objective-c. What exactly do the square braces around things signify and is there any difference between using that and using a period (I'm from a .NET world so this would be simpler for me).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

They both do the same thing in your example.  The `.` is a sort of shorthand used to access a property of an object.  `[]` are used to send a message to the object.  In your example, those happen to be the same thing.  You'll notice the difference if you try to send a message that doesn't directly map to a property name.

For example: `[myString length]` and `myString.length` are the same, but if you wanted to *set* the length (let's assume that makes sense for the example's sake), you'd need to do something like `[myString setLength:newLength]` or `myString.length = newLength`.  Besides that, there are messages that aren't the same as property names - like this example:

```
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"hello" withString:@"world"];
```

which has no meaningful equivalent using the `.` shorthand.

Comment: Interesting, I could have sworn that the compiler _used_ to let you send messages with no arguments to objects via the dot operator, even if the message didn't' map to a property name. Not that I ever did that, of course...

Comment: That's possible - I haven't tried it.  I wouldn't say that would be a good idea, though.  I certainly wouldn't want to write a program that relied on that behaviour.

Comment: @Carl: The compiler does indeed allow that. It doesn't distinguish between a read-only property and a parameterless method with the right return value. After all, the getter for a property is a parameterless method. After all, `myArray.count;` does in fact do a `[myArray count];`.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense.  I just think it's strange - if said method returned `void`, for example, would you be seeing code like `myObject.method;` around?  Weeeeeeird.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C uses messages, rather than methods, and that's the main syntax (the dot syntax was introduced as an alternative for simple get/set messages).  There are obviously significant similarities between methods and messages, but also differences.

In Objective-C, objects have complete flexibility in responding to a message at runtime.  They can handle a totally unexpected message, for instance by proxying it to another object.  Or, you could do things like map messages to columns at runtime.  This is based on a legacy going back to Smalltalk.

.NET only *just* got this flexibility with [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)/[`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx)/[`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider_methods.aspx).  Of course, in either language, method/message names defined at compile-time are usually more appropriate.  But there are notable use cases for dynamic ones.

Of course, Objective-C is a superset of C, so the `.` is used for other things (generally structs or unions).